# Can't display posts by filtering categories using isotope.js

Tags: categories, theme-development, filters, terms

I am currently building a wordpress theme using the isotope.js script which allows you to display articles on the same step by filtering their categories, I struggled a lot and I still can't get the expected result:

Here a link which will lead you to the expected result (a full version in HTML / CSS):

https://vgamerz.fr/isotopehelp/gallery/blog.html

Here my wordpress theme (PHP Files):

```
    <!-- Isotope Header -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h2 class="isotope-button-title">Isotope Blog Sort By</h2>
                <div id="isotope-filters" class="isotope-button-group">

                        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">Everything</a></li>
                        <?php 
                        $terms = get_categories(); // get all categories, but you can use any taxonomy
                        $count = count($terms); //How many are they?
                        if ( $count > 0 ){  //If there are more than 0 terms
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //for each term:
                            echo "<button class='button'><a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a></button>\n";
                            //create a list item with the current term slug for sorting, and name for label
                            }
                        } 
                            ?>

                </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Isotope Header -->

    <!--------------------------------------- end of header -------------------------------------->

        <!-- Isotope Grid -->
        <div class="row isotope-grid">
            <?php
                // Loops
                if(have_posts()):
                    while(have_posts()):
                        the_post(); ?>    
                                <!-- Isotope Grid-Item -->
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 isotope-grid-item  design " data-category="<?php get_the_category($post->ID); ?>">
                                    <div class="isotope-item">
                                        <a href="#"><div class="isotope-feature-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail() ?></div>
                                        <h3 class="isotope-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                        <p class="isotope-number">Post No: <?php the_ID(); ?></p>
                                        <p class="isotope-name">Author: <?php the_author() ?></p>
                                        <p class="isotope-type">Blog Type: <?php the_category() ?></p>
                                        <p class="isotope-datetime">Post Date: <?php the_date() ?> at <?php the_time() ?></p>
                                        <p class="isotope-blog"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        <!-- Isotope Grid-Item -->    
                        <?php 
                    Endwhile;
                Endif;
            ?>
            </div>
        <!-- End of Isotope Grid -->

        <!-- Begin of Footer -->

        </div>
    </body>
  </html> 
  <!-- End of Footer -->
```

JS File (isotope.js):

```
"use strict";

(function ($){

  $.fn.isotope_gallery = function(){    

        jQuery( function() {
            var $container = jQuery('.isotope-grid');
            // use imagesLoaded, instead of window.load
            $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
                $container.isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
                    // masonry is default layoutMode, no need to specify it
                });
            })
        });

        // init Isotope
        var $grid = $('.isotope-grid').isotope({
          itemSelector: '.isotope-grid-item',
          layoutMode: 'fitRows',
          isFitWidth: true,
          getSortData: {
            name: '.isotope-name',
            title: '.isotope-title',
            details: '.isotope-details',
            symbol: '.isotope-symbol',
            type: '.isotope-type',
            number: '.isotope-number',
            category: '[data-category]',
            //you can add hear more sorting class like those
          }
        });

        // filter functions
        var filterFns = {
          // show if number is greater than 50
          numberGreaterThan50: function() {
            var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
            return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
          },
          // show if name ends with -ium
          ium: function() {
            var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
            return name.match( /ium$/ );
          }
        };

        // bind filter button click
        $('#isotope-filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
          var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
          // use filterFn if matches value
          filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
          $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
        });

        // bind sort button click
        $('#isotope-sorts').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
          var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
          $grid.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue });
        });

        // change is-checked class on buttons
        $('.isotope-button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
          var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
          $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
            $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
            $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
          });
        });




        // Select and loop the container element of the elements you want to equalise
        $('.isotope-grid').each(function(){  

          // Cache the highest
          var highestBox = 0;

          // Select and loop the elements you want to equalise
          $('.isotope-grid-item', this).each(function(){

            // If this box is higher than the cached highest then store it
            if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
              highestBox = $(this).height(); 
            }

          });  

          // Set the height of all those children to whichever was highest 
          $('.isotope-grid-item',this).height(highestBox);

        }); 



  }

  $(this).isotope_gallery();


}(jQuery));
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <?php
        $categories     = get_the_category();
        $listCategories = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $listCategories[] = $category->slug;
        }
        ?>
        <!-- Isotope Grid-Item -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 isotope-grid-item <?php echo implode(' ', $listCategories); ?>" data-category="<?php echo implode(',', $listCategories); ?>">
            <div class="isotope-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="isotope-feature-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail() ?></div>
                    <h3 class="isotope-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <p class="isotope-number">Post No: <?php the_ID(); ?></p>
                    <p class="isotope-name">Author: <?php the_author() ?></p>
                    <p class="isotope-type">Blog Type: <?php the_category() ?></p>
                    <p class="isotope-datetime">Post Date: <?php the_date() ?> at <?php the_time() ?></p>
                    <p class="isotope-blog"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Isotope Grid-Item -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Posts can have more than one category, if you look at the source you will probably see [array] or if you put PHP error reporting on you will get an error.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help, I tried to replace my line of code with yours, my thumbnails no longer appear and I have an error instead and here is what it looks like: https://vgamerz.fr/isotopehelp/uncaught-error.html

Comment: Saw the error  `Uncaught Error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string` please see my updated answer.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but my thumbnails still don't appear and when I click on the buttons I don't have a url.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but my thumbnails still don't appear and when I click on the buttons I don't have a url. The error comes from there: data-category="<?php echo (',', get_the_category($listCategories)); ?>">, otherwise the request seems correct to me but there is no filtration of the articles by categories.

Comment: I realised something a bit late, apologies. You are using the css classes to filter so the `<?php echo implode(',', get_the_category($listCategories)); ?>` needs to echo there. The issue with your thumbnails i am unsure about, I tested it on my side and the thumbnails are working. please try the updated code.

Comment: The thumbnails appear again, but the filtration of articles by categories by clicking on the buttons does not work, indeed the buttons do not seem attached to any link.